# jar applet classpath

Tags: java, tags, jar, applet, classpath

I am trying to add a JAR file to a simple java applet which can be opened has an HTML.

This is my coding:

```
<applet code="AgniCorpContactsApp.class" 
codebase="/agnicorpcontacts" width="100" height="100" 
archive="AgniCorpContactsApp.jar">
</applet>
```

The location of the JAR file and all of the class files is: `C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\AgniCorpContacts\build\classes\`

Whenever I try to run the file in Internet explorer I get  this error:

```
load: class AgniCorpContactsApp.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AgniCorpContactsApp.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \agnicorpcontacts\AgniCorpContactsApp\class.class (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 ... 7 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AgniCorpContactsApp.class
```

What do I need to do in order to fix this? Is there a problem with the class path?

Answer (score 0):

The applet launcher cannot locate the class. This is probably because your applet tag (if you are using one) is not proper. You should have the codebase and code attributes for your applet if you are using multiple classes. Or optionally you can archive all the classes into a single jar archive which can be referenced by the applet. See [here](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html) for details

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while, but you need to serve your applet from a web server and include the jar file path relative to the webserver. I think you can do local testing using a tool sun delivers (Applet Runner?)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <applet code="AgniCorpContactsApp.class">
> ```

Remove the `.class` suffix. The `code` must denote the full qualified classname (including package), not the filename.